# Add Web Role Project in solution option freezed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I am trying to migrate a small ASP.NET 'web site' (not web application) to Windows Azure. I have added the website to the solution by Add Existing Project> Selecting the *.sln file.
After this, when I right click on the Web Role in Windows Azure, the "Add Web Role Project in solution" is freezed and so, I am not able to create the web role?
[image]

Why is the option freezed? What's going wrong in here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert your web site to a web application before you can upload it to Azure.

To do this, follow these instructions - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Hi,

I tried to convert the website into application going step by step according to the above walkthrough. At the last step, when I did a build of the web app, it has started showing huge number of errors. Here's the screensoht: http://i.imgur.com/sDSPa.png

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of those files - e.g. I'm looking to see if all your pages have class name "_Default"?

Comment: Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/XDlac.png. Looks like all of the page have the class name "_Default"

Comment: In which case... you'll have to manually (or using a script of some kind) change each page so that it's class name is unique (e.g. AddProfile.aspx could be called AddProfile) - sounds like its going to be boring, but should be quite quick. Might be quicker to do outside of VisualStudio.

Comment: For the first time, I removed 496 errors in one build :P Thanks!